# Detect Integer Overflow in Input

Tags: c++, c, integer, overflow

Is there a way in C or C++ to check whether the number provided by the user is outside the range of an integer type?

For instance, let us assume that we are using 16-bit signed integers with a range of -32768 to 32767.

If the user enters 55555 into the program, this will be wrapped to become a negative number so that if you are using a function which can accept any number, the result would be wrong.

Is there a way in C or C++ to determine whether the number provided by the user is within the range of the integer type?

---

Update: I am using the numbers in a simple subtraction program which accepts two numbers and subtracts the second from the first.

Comment: What programming language do you use? C++ and C aren't the same, particularly in the area of reading input.

Comment: @aam1r - I don't think this is actually a duplicate. That link is regarding detecting integer overflow during a mathematical operation, Matthew's question is regarding integer overflow when getting a value from the user.

Comment: @Mike: Sorry, I misread the question. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > If the user enters 55555 into the program, this will be wrapped to become a negative number

Not always. It depends upon how you read the number. If you use, `operator>>`, for example, that value will **not** be wrapped, it will be rejected.

> > Is there a way in C or C++ to determine whether the number provided by the user is within the range of the integer type?

In C++, just use `operator>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  signed short int i;
  std::cin >> i;
  if(std::cin)
    std::cout << "You entered a valid number!\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Aw c'mon, play by the rules.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using something like `strtol` it'll set `errno` to `ERANGE` if an overflow occurs

Comment: Correct, but I believe the concern was over whether one could detect an overflow during the conversion process from text to an integer. Once you have it in an integer, you can then do your own range checking to make sure it's within range of whatever datatype you are casting down to (ie short).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in C or C++ to check whether the number provided by the
>   user is outside the range of an integer type?

It depends of what function you are using (`strtol` can do that for example). Check the documentation.

Comment: `strtol` is for `long`. The function for `int` is `strtoimax`.

Comment: @Barmar That's for `intmax_t`, which usually is larger than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between int's and uint's is how INTERPRET them.  Your problem has no solution, if it so critical for you consider switching to floating point argument, checking value and typecasting. Update: I thought you want  run time check  function argument value provided by another programmer, not console input.

Comment: While true most of the time in practice and especially true in the CPU, the compiler and the language standard beg to differ.