# Compare uint8_t and uint16_t in c++

Tags: c++, compare, uint8t, uint16

i would like to test if a value of an input variable passed one byte size or know so i write this code

```
{
    uint8_t x;
    cout << " enter x" << endl;
    cin  >> hex >> x;
    cout << hex << x;
    uint8_t y ;  
    y = x >> 4 ;
    cout << hex << y;
    if ( y == 0 )
    {
        cout << " succes, coorect value for x";
    }
    if (y >  0)
    {
        /*here i supoosed that x = 0xfff and when shifting, y would be 0xff but y is uint8 so it's just for compare
        std::cout << "fail, ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how to test if the user type two or more byte in uint8.
And tell him to retype the value of just one byte.that's why i tried to compare uint8_t to uint16_t.

Comment: Given that `y` is an unsigned value, can you [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how could `y` possibly be ever less than 0?

Comment: `if ( y < 0 )` this will never be true. `y` is an unsigned integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Detect Integer Overflow in Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938053/detect-integer-overflow-in-input)

Comment: [GCC warns](https://godbolt.org/g/TCuznK) about this by the way.

Comment: One problem is that `uint8_t` might be `unsigned char` and `istream` has an [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) that reads this as a character and not as a number.

Comment: Sorry for compare y to zero in fact i would like to compare to zero i would like if y ==0

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is that you are testing for a `negative` value in an `unsigned integer`. The `if(y < 0)` part will always be false.

Now, from my understanding you want to filter values that are greater than `1Byte`. You know, that for a given `byte` you have `2^8 - 1` range of values, that is, the unsigned number lies in the range `[0-255]`. Thus, your problem is reduced to a simple check, that is, `if the input value is greater than 255, throw away that input`. (Ofc you have to check for `< 0` values)

There are other solutions to this but without any context I can't provide a precise answer. Hope the above simplification helps.

Comment: yeah , i see that but i would like to oblige the user to enter a correct number of byte to a given variable type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a value is in the range of a small type, you have to assign it to a bigger type first. You simply cannot do the check with the small type itself because it can never contain that too huge value you want to check for.

```
uint16_t tempX;
uint8_t x;
cin >> hex >> tempX;
if (tempX > 0xff)
    cout << "error";
else
    x = (uint8_t)tempX;
```

Comment: and when i enter a tempX 0xfffff..uint16_t can't support it.